# How to pass image from python to laravel

Tags: php, python, laravel, shell, python-imaging-library

I have a python script that generates an image using pillow library, I want to use as my backend  and let the laravel manage it, 
How i have to pass the python generated image back to the laravel requset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to encode the file to base64 in python side and print it to the shell,
and at the laravel side decode it from base64.
Here are the key codes:

Python3:

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
background = Image.new('RGBA', (500, 500))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
d.text((10, 10), "Hello World", fill=(255, 255, 0))
imgByteArr = BytesIO()
background.save(imgByteArr, format='PNG')
imgByteArr = base64.b64encode(imgByteArr.getvalue())
print(imgByteArr)
```

Laravel:

```
public function newImage()
{
    $process = new Process('python3 /path-to-script/shell.py');
    $process->run();
    if ( ! $process->isSuccessful())
    {
        return abort(404);
    }

    return response(base64_decode(str_replace_first('b', '', $process->getOutput())))->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');

}
```